# Is it possible to expand host capacity or bandwidth automatically?

Tags: hosting, cpanel

I have a reseller account hosting, using WHM cPanel. I want to sell "expandable hosting service", that mean it flexible.

First, every plan is started with 500MB for example. But when they use nearly 400MB, can we make it automatic grow/expand hosting to 600MB or higher? If they not reach the limit, the host still remain 500MB.

Second, is it possible to do that? Even if I have to hire some developer, can I do it?

Thank you so much.

Comment: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/ShowAccountInformation use this cpanel api to get the disk usage and also to modify

Comment: yes you can do that using the same api itself, check the diskspace and modify it

Answer (score 0):

If you create a system by using the API of WHM / Cpanel and cron tasks, yes.

- Cron
- Purpose of the task. Using the API to get the disk consumption of each account. If the account AAAA> XXX with the API increase that value.

[http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/vief/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/WebHome#cPanel  WHM's API](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/vief/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/WebHome#cPanel%20%20WHM%27s%20API)